# Labels in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In visual basic , when you create a label in form view (via click and drag) is it possible to make the label have both a string and a variable included in it?

*

```
turns=1
label1.text = ("Turn:"(turns))
```

*

for example , so that label 1 will display

```
*Turn 1*
```

Comment: What version of VB are you asking about?

Comment: This dosen't work. Tried it in the code using

label1.text = ("Turn:"(turns))

Answer (score 1):

`label1.text = "Turn: " & turns.ToString()`

Comment: is that the code for it? Or are you saying that it is too stringy?

Comment: Try it. I believe it should work.  The ToString() is used to convert "turns" to a string value.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking VB.Net, or something else?

In .Net:

```
turns = 1
Label1.Text = $"Turn {turns}"
```

Comment: How can you tell which is which? I have the visual basic express edition from microsoft. I am using the windows forms application utility.

Answer (score 1):

Every control has the `Tag` property which can store any object reference. However, you can't easily give a label a sort of "format string" and then make it update whenever you change a variable, if that's what you were thinking of.

If you were *just* talking about formatting the label to use a variable's value in the text, then you can't do that within the designer - you'll have to do it somewhere in the code (e.g. in the constructor, after the designer code has been called).

Comment: I thought so. wasn't sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in the Designer window (where you do the positioning and layout of your form). You'll have to implement that functionality in your code.

Let's assume the label's name is **Label1**, you can write this code where you'd like the label's text to change. For example, in the event handler, function or subroutine that is called when the number of turns changes.

```
Label1.Text = "Turn: " & turns.ToString()
```